# YOLO: Wrong annotation: class_id = 6. But class_id should be [from 0 to 0]

Tags: keras, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

I'm trying to train YOLO for object detection based on 8 classes by using Darknet. However, while training I receive the error

```
Wrong annotation: class_id = 4. But class_id should be [from 0 to 0], file: data/obj/images/IMG_8943.txt
```

`IMG_8943.txt` is one of my text files where I store my annotations which have been obtained with labelImg. I don't really understand why I'm getting this error since I have specified the number of classes within my config file:

```
[net]
# Testing
batch=8
subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=166
classes = 8
width=416
height=416
#filters = 39
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 4000
policy=steps
steps=400000,450000
scales=.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

######################

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=18
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 6,7,8
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=1
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1


[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 61



[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=18
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=1
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1



[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 36



[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=18
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 0,1,2
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=1
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1
```

Furthermore, I have used the following commands to set up  object names:

```
!echo -e 'classes= 1\ntrain  = data/train.txt\nvalid  = data/test.txt\nnames = data/obj.names\nbackup = /mydrive/yolov32' > data/obj.data
```

Can anybody give me a hint what's missing?

Answer (score 1):

Change the class id for each .txt file for all classes starting from 0 for first class till 7 (as total classes are 8).

Second is change the batch size in testing from 8 to 1.